# How to combine 3 action before running loop?

Tags: c#

the code

```
  Settings setting_ = .... // not null 

  foreach( var item in ItemsCollection)
  {
       var tt1 = item.GetTT1();
       var tt2 = item.GetTT2();

       if( tt2 != null && tt1 != null )
       {
           if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( settings_.Name ) )
           {
                tt2.Rename( tt1, setting_.Name );
           }

           if( setting_ .Settings != null )
           {
                 tt2.ChangeSettings( tt1, setting_.Settings );
           }

           if( setting_ .Location != null )
           {
                 tt2.ChangeLocation( tt1, setting_.Location ); 
           }
       }
  }
```

Because the setting_ is not change at any iteration of the foreach loop => i need to check only once the 3 if .... ( before get into the foreach loop )

But the tt1 & tt2 are change each foreach iteration ...

How can i write this code better with only one check of the setting_ ?

one possible is this

```
    private void defineAction( TT1 tt1 , TT2 tt2, Setting setting )
    {

        List<Action> action = new List<Action>();
        if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( settings_.Name ) )
           {

                action.Add( () => tt2.Rename( tt1, setting_.Name )
           }

           if( setting_ .Settings != null )
           {
                 action.Add( () => tt2.ChangeSettings( tt1, setting_.Settings );
           }

           if( setting_ .Settings != null )
           {
                 action.Add( () => tt2.ChangeLocation( tt1, setting_.Location ); 
           } 
    }
```

and use the List to make the action ..
but i need to call this method each iteration and i want to make it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while to decipher your question but I think I understand you. Here's what you could do:

```
var actions = new List<Action<Item, Item>>();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(setting_.Name))
{
    actions.Add((tt1, tt2) =>
    {
        if (tt1 != null && tt2 != null) 
            tt2.Rename(tt1, setting_.Name);
    });
}

if (setting_.Settings != null)
{
    actions.Add((tt1, tt2) =>
    {
        if (tt1 != null && tt2 != null)
            tt2.ChangeSettings(tt1, setting_.Settings);
    });
}

if (setting_.Settings != null)
{
    actions.Add((tt1, tt2) =>
    {
        if (tt1 != null && tt2 != null)
            tt2.ChangeLocation(tt1, setting_.Location);
    });
}

foreach (var item in itemCollection)
{
    var tt1 = item.GetTT1();
    var tt2 = item.GetTT2();
    actions.ForEach(a => a(tt1, tt2));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Now that I understand from your previous comments what you're trying to do you can create a collection of actions rather than using simple if statements.  If may or may not be better performing, since you'd have the cost of the iterator.  If the collection is large, it would probably be useful to check if you're going to do anything before iterating over it.

```
  Settings setting_ = .... // not null 
  var actions = new List<Action<TT1,TT2>>();
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(setting_.Name))
  {
      actions.Add((t1,t2) => t2.Rename(t1, setting_.Name););
  }

  if (setting_.Settings != null)
  {
      actions.Add((t1,t2) => t2.ChangeSettings(t1, settings_.Settings));
  }

  if (setting_.Location != null)
  {
      actions.Add((t1,t2) => t2.ChangeLocation(t1, settings_.Location));
  }

  if (actions.Any())
  {
      foreach( var item in ItemsCollection)
      {
         var tt1 = item.GetTT1();
         var tt2 = item.GetTT2();

         if (tt1 == null || tt2 == null)
         {
             continue;
         }

         foreach (var action in actions)
         {
             action(tt1,tt2);
         }
      }
  }
```

Though I still think it's easier if you just precompute the conditions - I was confused by `setting_.Settings` before.

```
Settings setting_ = .... // not null
var changeName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(setting_.Name);
var changeSetting = setting_.Settings != null;
var changeLocation = setting_.Location != null;

if (changeName || changeSetting || changeLocation)
{
    foreach (var item in ItemCollection)
    {
        var tt1 = item.getTT1();
        var tt2 = item.getTT2();

        if (tt1 == null || tt2 == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (changeName)
        {
            tt2.Rename(tt1, setting_.Name);
        }

        if (changeSetting)
        {
            tt2.ChangeSettings(tt1, settings_.Settings);
        }

        if (changeLocation)
        {
            tt2.ChangeLocation(tt1, settings_.Location);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you change it to bool => i want to make some action collection that can hold 1 .. 3 action accourding to the setting_

Comment: setting can't be null

Comment: @Yanshof I updated my answer based on your feedback.